# Mouse Stuck In Upper Right Corner After USB Joystick Insertion

Tags: usb, xorg, mouse, joystick

I'm relatively new to Linux so I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but if not I would appreciate a point in the right direction.

I am having a strange issue where when I insert my Joystick into my Ubuntu computer the mouse cursor automatically steers to the upper right corner of the screen. When I use a normal mouse I am able to move the cursor around, however it always returns back to the upper right corner of the screen.
Moving the Joystick itself resolves the issue but it would be preferable to not have it get stuck in the first place.

**System Information**
Ubuntu Version: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Joystick Maker: AXIS Communications
Joystick Model: AXIS T8311 Joystick

**Personal Notes / Things I've Tried**
After monitoring the input device files under `/dev/input` using the `evtest` tool I found that when the cursor is continually returning to the upper right corner, there are no actual kernel input events being fired.

So it seems like Xorg is having an issue with the initial coordinate values from the device?
I did end up monitoring Xorg events and when the mouse is bugging out it seems like there are tons of scroll wheel events firing within Xorg. This stops after moving the Joystick.
(I can provide more specific event information if needed)

Monitoring udev and sysfs it seems like the AXIS Joystick gets split into 2 input devices. One for a Mouse, and one a Joystick type. Both have corresponding input files under `/dev/input` however the strange thing is only the Joystick device file gets movement events.
Monitoring the mouse device file using `evtest` doesn't show any events firing at all.

I am currently wondering if Xorg is checking both device files but since there is no information for the mouse device file it fails to setup an initial state? Not sure how to test that theory though. (Messing around with the xorg.conf file doesn't seem to help any)

I'm sorry for the long post, but this device isn't officially supported for Linux so I was hoping to get some sort of resolution elsewhere. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!
Steve